# undefined class constant 'CONDITION_OPTIONS'

Tags: php

i have a class Bicycle where the constant variable `protected const CONDITION_OPTIONS` and whenever i try to echo returned value it coming from `condition()` method this message appear

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'CONDITION_OPTIONS' in C:\Users\Khaled\Desktop\sites\chain_gang\private\classes\bicycle.class.php:64 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Khaled\Desktop\sites\chain_gang\public\bicycles.php(38): Bicycle->condition() #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Khaled\Desktop\sites\chain_gang\private\classes\bicycle.class.php on line 64
```

please check the code below...

```
<?php

class Bicycle {
      protected $condition_id;
      protected const CONDITION_OPTIONS = [
   1 => 'Beat up',
   2 => 'Decent',
   3 => 'Good',
   4 => 'Great',
   5 => 'Like New'
  ];


  public function __construct($arg=[]){
   $this->condition_id = $arg['condition_id'] ?? 3;
  }


  public function condition(){
   if($this->condition_id > 0){
    return self::CONDITION_OPTIONS[$this->condition_id];
   }else{
    return "Unknown";
   }

  }
}



$arg = ['condition_id' => 2];
$bike = new Bicycle($arg);
echo $bike->condition();
?>
```

Comment: Your example works fine for me: https://3v4l.org/PA0WW Maybe your actual code has a typo in, and you accidentally fixed it while posting the answer here?

Comment: Works fine for me in php 7.1 - returns `Decent`. Are you sure you're using php >= 7.1?

Comment: @aynber Constants can *only* be used with static accessors. `$this->FOO` would be property `$FOO`, `$this::FOO` is just the same as `get_class($this)::FOO`.

Comment: @IMSoP ah, thanks. I've never used a class constant from inside the same class before.

Comment: yes i think so because i copied the code and past it in my project and now it works great xD thanks dude :D @IMSoP